# Angular 2 Returning data from subscribe

Tags: angular, observable

this is my service

```
 countGroupByEtat(): Observable<number[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url + 'GroupByEtat', { headers: this.prepareHeaders() })
        .map((res: Response) => {
            let object: Array<any> = [];
            let jsonResults: Array<any> = res.json();
            jsonResults.forEach((jsonResult) => {
                object.push(jsonResult);
            });
            return object;
        })
}
```

and my method

```
  getGroupByEtat(): number[] {
    this.serviceDossier.countGroupByEtat()
      .subscribe((data: number[]) => {
        this.objects = data;
        console.log("subsc"+ this.objects)

      })
    return this.objects;
  }
```

When I want to obtain the value of `this.objects` after the closing of `subscribe` I receive an array that is empty, help !

Comment: Check `return this.object` in method and `return object` in Service

Comment: @k11k2 the object in service is full but for this.object in method => in subscribe is full but out of subscribe is empty

Answer (score 2):

Change it to :

```
 getGroupByEtat(): number[] {
    return this.serviceDossier.countGroupByEtat()
      .subscribe((data: number[]) => {
        this.objects = data;
        console.log("subsc"+ this.objects)

        return this.objects;
      })

  }
```

Comment: j'ai déjà  pensé à faire ça.. mais cette façon ne me permet pas de returner un tableau

Comment: Quel est le résultat ou l'erreur obtenu ?

Comment: je reçois une tableau vide

Comment: Et à la console ? Un tableau avec des valeurs ? Il faut s'assurer que ton service ne renvoie pas des valeurs vides

Comment: le problème c que lorsque je met un console.log à l’intérieur de subscribe je reçois un tableau remplit une fois je sors de subscribe le tableau est vide.. je sais pas où est le problème!! :/

Comment: This just won't work, and please use English.